# Bootstrap 3 How to set Auto Padding For <a>Tag to Cover entire Li element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 I have a responsive UI and I need to make following a links in the li to cover entire the `li` element. This can be hard coded by setting absolute padding value like

```
padding: 22px 32px;
```

but this is making conflict so I was hoping if we can set an auto cover padding for them?

```css
.toc-menu{
  background-color: #3f4652;
  padding:0px;
}
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left:0;

}
ul>li {
  min-height:60px;
  list-style-type:none; 
  text-align:center;

}

ul>li>a {
  text-align:center;
  line-height:60px;
  color:#fff;
  background:tomato;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-1 toc-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-11"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add class `btn-block` to your links -> `<li><a href="#" class="btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>`

Comment: Thanks a lots Morphus!